Informatica WRT_8410 Error, with [Error=]
In informatica I am getting this error
WRT_8410 : Error writing file [error=]
Unable to understand what's causing this error.

Hi - you’re going to have to provide a lot more information than that before anyone can help you. What are you trying to do? What are your sources/targets? What additional information does the log file provide? Etc

a generic solution give n infa community - https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/118450?language=en_US please check more details in session log and then inform us.
